# Can I claim an Imgur album that I made before I signed up?

Tags: imgur

I uploaded an album, then later signed up.

Is there any way I can 'claim' that album under my account?

Answer (score 1):

Probably still "No" but definitely "No" at the time this was asked. [See](https://community.imgur.com/t/when-i-submit-an-album-without-logging-in-i-should-be-given-a-short-code-i-can-use-to-connect-said-album-to-my-account/15743/2) from Dec '15:

> Unfortunately there is no way to associate an image uploaded anonymously with an account. You can use the deletion link provided on upload or submit it to [http://imgur.com/removalrequest](https://imgur.com/removalrequest) then re-upload while logged in, but your view count will reset. Sorry for the trouble. I have submitted your feedback to the team so we can look into how this process can be improved.